# Is there a way to delete only documents/data of an app without deleting the app itself?

Tags: iphone, ios

I am running out of space on my iPhone and since iOS 5 I can see the worst offenders in Settings -> General -> Usage.
Some apps while being very small themselves have accumulated a lot of data. I want to keep the app itself on the phone but would like to get rid of the data.

Is there a way to delete the data/documents directly on the phone without deleting the app itself?
Or is re-installing the app the only possible way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the application doesn't provide a way to delete documents, uninstalling and reinstalling the app is definitively the best option here.

Comment: Hmm, are there any "jailbroken power apps" (like iFile) that can achieve this?

Comment: Beware that the application might to be listed in the App Store but the minimum required OS version made the above the OS version you have, in which case removing then installing the application to remove its data won't work (it just happened to me with Google Drive). Also, sometimes applications get delisted from App Store.