# Delete app data without deleting app

Tags: iphone, ios

One of the apps I have installed is not working super well and I'd like to try deleting its data to see if that helps.

Usually, when you delete an app on iOS, it warns you that all data will be deleted. As such, [the common advice is simply deleting the app and then redownloading it from the App Store](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/33799/is-there-a-way-to-delete-only-documents-data-of-an-app-without-deleting-the-app).

However, this app has been delisted from the App Store, meaning it can't be redownloaded, so I don't want to delete it. What else can I do?

For what it's worth, this is an iPhone 4 running iOS 7.

Comment: Beware that the application might to be listed in the App Store but the minimum required OS version made the above the OS version you have, in which case removing then installing the  application to remove its data won't work as well. (it just happened to me with Google Drive)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the version of iTunes you have you may be able to do this. You need the last one that has App Management built in. [This one](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208079) to be specific.

As long as the needed app is listed in iTunes and you can find the .ipa file on your hard drive, it should be safe to delete the app from your phone and then sync with iTunes to put it back.

It has been a long time since I tried this, you might want to wait till someone else who has done this more recently can verify this *just to be safe*

Comment: Thanks. I think I might have other delisted apps that I don't care about, so I'll see if I can test it with one of those.